# Is this FIR filter considered symmetric?

Tags: fft, finite-impulse-response

My goal is to generate linear phase FIR filters. Currently, I am generating an array of frequency response magnitudes for the positive frequencies and then I mirror those with the complex conjugate and take the inverse FFT of that.

In the image bellow, you can see that the peak of the impulse response is centered at position 33 and the value of position 1 is not equal to the value of position 64. I don't know how it could be since this has an even number of coefficients.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to go back to high-school algebra (assuming you had a good math program in high school).

The answer to "Is $f(n)$ symmetric?" is shorthand for "Is $f(n)$ symmetric about some $n_0$?".

For some function $f(n)$ to be symmetric about some $n_0$, then either $f(n_0 + \Delta n) = f(n_0 - \Delta n)\ \forall\ n_0 \pm \Delta_n \in n$ (even symmetry), or $f(n_0 + \Delta n) = -f(n_0 - \Delta n)\ \forall\ n_0 \pm \Delta_n \in n$ (odd symmetry).

In your case, strictly speaking, your filter taps *cannot* be symmetric about $n_0 = 33$, because for $\Delta n = 32$, $n_0 - \Delta n = 1$, which is in the interval $[1, 64]$, but $n_0 + \Delta n = 65$, which is not.

If you want to have a filter that is symmetric around some integer sample (i.e., $n_0 = 33$), then it must have an odd number of elements.

For FIR filters, an element at the end of the filter with a value of zero is effectively not there, so you *could* set the filter value at $n = 1$ to zero, and then your filter would be symmetric around $n_0 = 33$.  You could arrive at the same effect in the frequency domain, and nearly the same effect in the time domain, by then shifting the filter one sample to the left and inserting a zero at $n = 64$).

Answer (score 0):

The following web page will help you. Read the initial part of the discussion there and then pay close attention to the section titled: "Designing the Filter."
http://www.dspguide.com/ch16/1.htm